# How to make the label text to negate-color against background

Tags: text, labeling, textures

This is current solution from a friend:

```
Block[{rawpic = 
   ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
      ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[x, y, 1 - x - y]], 
      BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False, Frame -> False] // Image //
     ImageCrop, d, pos}, d = ImageDimensions@rawpic;
 pos = Rasterize[
       Style["It's a lable", 25, Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier New"]] //
       Binarize // ImageData // Position[#, 0] & // 
   Round[{#[[1]] + d[[1]]*0.8, #[[2]] + d[[2]]*0.2}] & /@ # &;
 MapAt[1 - # &, ImageData[rawpic][[;; , ;; , ;; 3]], pos] // Image // 
  SetAlphaChannel[#, Binarize[#, 0.01]] &]
```

the effect is:

[image]

Is there a more convenient way to do it? The best is about how to use `Style`,and the result is a vectorgraph.Can Anybody give some suggstions?

Comment: I find this question vague as it is currently posed. What do you mean by "make the label text negate color"? What definition of "convenient" would you use to accept an answer?

Comment: "make the label text negate color" is negate to the label's background,the "convenient" is mean a better method no need to cope with the pixel in current solution.And I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [code by MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95535/280) as a start and assuming that under "negate-color" you mean the result of applying `ColorNegate`:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[x, y, 1 - x - y]], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None];
text = Graphics[{Inset[
     Style["It's a label", White, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 32], 
     Scaled[{0.5, 0.2}]]}, Options[plot], Background -> Black];
i = ImageCompose[plot, 
  SetAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@ImageMultiply[Show[plot, Background -> Black], text], text]]
```

> [image]

Assuming that you wish to have the text selectable after exporting to a vector format you can add completely transparent text over the raster version of the text - then after `Export`ing to PDF the text will be selectable:

```
i2 = Show[i, 
   Graphics[{Inset[
      Style["It's a label", Opacity[0.01], FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 32], 
      Scaled[{0.5, 0.2}]]}, Options[plot]]];

Export["i2.pdf", i2]
```

(I was forced to set `Opacity[0.01]` instead of `Opacity[0]` because with the latter the text is removed on `Export`ing - superfluously "smart" behavior of `Export`.)

Here is how the exported file looks in Adobe Acrobat when the text is selected:

[image: screenshot]

---

### UPDATE

Here is completely vector-styled implementation without resorting to the tricks like transparent textual overlay.

At first we determine the positions of the characters in the image:

```
ps = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[text, .95], "Centroid"];
Show[Image@text, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Table[Text[p[[1]], p[[2]], Background -> Yellow], {p, ps}]}]
```

> [image: plot]

We see that the characters are counted non-sequentially, so we write the correct ordering by hands inserting zeros where the whitespace characters should be placed:

```
ordering = {1, 5, 2, 6, 0, 7, 0, 3, 8, 9, 10, 4};
```

Extract colors for the characters, negate them and apply the ordering:

```
colors = ColorNegate[RGBColor @@@ PixelValue[plot, ps[[;; , 2]]][[;; , ;; 3]]];
colorsSorted = colors[[ordering]];
```

Style the characters and combine everything together:

```
chs = Characters["It's a label"];
styledchs = 
  MapThread[Style[#1, #2, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 32] /. 
     List :> (## &[]) &, {chs, colorsSorted}];
styledText = Graphics[Inset[Row[styledchs], Scaled[{0.5, 0.2}]]];
Show[plot, styledText]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: 1,(*ordering = SortBy[ps, #[[2, 1]] &][[All, 1]];*)
2,(*chs = DeleteCases[Characters["It's a label"], " "];*)
All the way,your answer is very nice and your Opacity is so cute.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) to position an [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) containing appropriately [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html)d text wherever you want in the graph; a relative position is specified through a [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) directive. Use [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html)`-> None` to eliminate the empty space around your figure.

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[x, y, 1 - x - y]],
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False, Frame -> False,

 (* new stuff *)
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Style["It's a label", White, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 32],
   Scaled[{0.5, 0.2}]
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: your label's color is constant white,which will not adapt to a negate color against background.